# Guttenburg and Classic Editor - How to use the custom guttenburg block in classic editor?

Tags: wordpress, function, wordpress-gutenberg, gutenberg-blocks

I am making a theme, in that I have created some custom blocks for guttenburg but the problem is how the user can use the guttenburg blocks if he/she switches to classic editor.

For an example,

Let suppose I have created a button block ( I know it's already there ) but a custom one so how the user is able to access it, when he/she swithces to the classic editor.

Is it really possible or not. If yes than how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gutenberg is a `React.js` based editor and an advancement to classic editor. WordPress provides us action hooks through which we bind data or our blocks to Gutenberg Editor.

Classic editor is simple editor which I think using just simple JavaScript so you can't use Gutenberg blocks on it as they are React based. Although you can render the same frontend using `shortcode` to give user option to embed data through classic editor but it will be waste of time because you have an advanced editor already present.

As far as I work on Gutenberg I can say that Gutenberg is very client friendly, so it's better to use and prefer that.